# Add a function into a onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, single-page-application, material-ui

I want to use React.js to build a single page application and I want to create a list in a material-ui drawer. I want to add an element into an array every time I press a button but I don't how to write this function.

Here is my buttom:

```
 <RaisedButton
            label="Next"
            primary={true}
            onClick={this.onNext}
          />
```

Here is onNext function:

```
onNext = (event) => {
    const current = this.state.controlledDate;
    const date = current.add(1, 'days');
    this.setState({
      controlledDate: date
    });
    this.getImage(moment(date));
  }
```

And this is the code I want to add into onNext function:

```
menuItems.push(<MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>{this.state.image.date}</MenuItem>);
```

Comment: Did you bind the onclick function (onNext)? eg: `this.onNext = this.onNext.bind(this);`

Comment: @JayHarris No, that's fine: `this` in `onNext` defined as arrow function should have correct reference to class instance

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that adds drawer menu items using state

```
const { RaisedButton, MuiThemeProvider, Drawer, getMuiTheme, MenuItem } = MaterialUI;

class Sample extends React.Component {

  state = {
    open: false,
    items: [],
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true })
  }

  onNext = () => {
    this.setState(state => {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        items: state.items.concat([
          {
            // add any other button props here (date, image, etc.)
            text: `Item ${state.items.length + 1}`
          }
        ]),
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer
          openSecondary={true}
          width={200}
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>{item.text}</MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Drawer>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Next"
          primary={true}
          style={{ margin: 12 }}
          onClick={this.onNext} />          
        <RaisedButton
          label="Open Drawer"
          primary={true}
          style={{ margin: 12 }}
          onClick={this.handleOpen} />          
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Sample />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jprogd/eq533rzL/

Hope it should give you an idea how to go further